# Visual studio 2019 & VS 2017 not able to discover tests

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-test-runner

I had everything working until a few days ago. After latest update of VS, VS is not able to discover tests. I have tried updating MSTest.TestFramework, MSTest.TestAdapter, Microsoft.Net.Test.sdk nuget pacakges as well but VS studio is still not able to discover the tests.

```
Warning : A testsettings file or a vsmdi file is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter.
[12/21/2019 11:19:36 AM Warning] No test matches the given testcase filter `FullyQualifiedName=Microsoft.ConvAI.FrontEnd.End2EndTests.ConvAIClientTests.VerifyBotGetsRecognitions` in D:\Git\Skyman\conversational-ai\src\Testing\Microsoft.ConvAI.FrontEnd.End2EndTests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.ConvAI.FrontEnd.End2EndTests.dll
[12/21/2019 11:19:36 AM Informational] ========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:07.7975681) ==========
```

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: You probably should run the command line tool to see if more log entries can be made, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was runsettings file which I had to uncheck "Run settings file" from "configure run setting" option under test menu.